# Check if module is installed in Jupyter, rather than in kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have a base conda environment, from which I have run `jupyter lab`:

```
(base) $ jupyter lab
```

Then, from another virtual environment, I have done

```
(venv) $ pip install ipywidgets
(venv) $ pip install ipykernel
(venv) $ python -m ipykernel install --user --name my-kernel
```

So, then, in Jupyter Lab (which was started from my `base` environment), I can open a notebook and select `my-kernel` as the kernel.

From within such a notebook(which is running `my-kernel`), how can I detect whether JupyterLab (which was started from my `base` environment) has `ipywidgets` installed?

I cannot just do `import ipywidgets` and see if I get `ModuleNotFoundError` because that would only detect whether ipywidgets was installed in `my-kernel` - however, I'm trying to find out if it is installed in my `base` environment.

Answer (score 1):

It partially depends on how you are creating your virtual environments and which OS you are using. I.e. for conda users, this will be different.  You can make a subprocess call to pip in the base environment and return a list of installed packages.

```
import sys
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

def is_installed_in_base(pkg_name):
    pip = Path(sys.base_prefix).joinpath('bin', 'pip')  # Linux
    # pip = Path(sys.base_prefix).joinpath('Scripts', 'pip.exe')  # Windows
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        [pip.as_posix(), 'list'], 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    packages = out.decode().lower().split('\n')[2:]
    packages = [pkg.split()[0].strip() for pkg in packages if pkg]
    return pkg_name.lower() in packages

is_installed_in_base('ipywidgets')
# returns:
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe

```
import ipywidgets
print(ipywidgets.__file__)
```

Comment: why? would would this tell me?

Comment: it will tell you the file path to the ipywidgets that you had imported

Comment: true, but how does that help to tell whether `ipywidgets` is installed in the environment from which I launched jupyter lab?

Comment: check the path ... compare it  to your expected path ...

Comment: that'll tell me that `ipywidgets` is indeed installed in `my-kernel`. It tells me nothing about whether or not it was installed in the `base` environment

Comment: base environment, just means its installed to a path ... just check that path matches... to quote inigo montoya "these words do not mean what you think they mean" `base` environment means nothing except that its in a specific install location

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood the question, sorry. Thanks anyway for trying to help